# Stored procedure update needs all parameters passed in order to work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, isnull

Hi I've been trying to make this stored procedure so that it can update an individual parameter without having to put all the parameters. I want the previous values to remain the same if the passed value is empty or null. As I have it now I have to pass all the parameters in order for the procedure to work.
Please help, thanks in advance.

```
create procedure U_DIS_UpdateProject
(
@projectID CHAR(4),
@projectName varchar(50), 
@firmName varchar(50),
@fundedbudget decimal(16,2), 
@startDate date, 
@status varchar(25), 
@projectTypeCode char(5),
@projectManager char(8) 
) as
begin
UPDATE Project
SET  
projectName =ISNULL(@projectName,projectName), 
firmName =ISNULL(@firmName,firmName), 
fundedbudget =ISNULL(@fundedbudget,fundedbudget), 
startDate =ISNULL(@startDate,startDate), 
status =ISNULL(@status,status), 
projectTypeCode =ISNULL(@projectTypeCode,projectTypeCode),
projectManager =ISNULL(@projectManager,projectManager)
WHERE @projectID=projectID
```

end
go

exec U_DIS_UpdateProject  @projectID = 'A003', @projectName = 'Le Chateau', @firmName ='Gotham       Restaurants'
  go

Comment: are you sure you have to put all the parameters? I don't think you have to.  You should be able to just update projectd, projectName, firmName without specify the other columns

Comment: SQL is the standard that most RDBMS implement. SQL Server is Microsoft's RDBMS product..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use CASE statements to check each one. It's similar to what you have in your example, but this will also catch empty strings.

```
create procedure U_DIS_UpdateProject
(
@projectID CHAR(4),
@projectName varchar(50), 
@firmName varchar(50),
@fundedbudget decimal(16,2), 
@startDate date, 
@status varchar(25), 
@projectTypeCode char(5),
@projectManager char(8) 
) as
begin
UPDATE Project
SET  
projectName = 
        (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@projectName,'')='' THEN projectName
            ELSE @projectName
        END),
firmName =
        (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@firmName,'')='' THEN firmName
            ELSE @firmName
        END),
fundedbudget =
    (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@fundedbudget,'')='' THEN fundedbudget
            ELSE @fundedbudget
        END),
startDate =
    (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@startDate,'')='' THEN startDate
            ELSE @startDate
        END),
status =
    (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@status,'')='' THEN [status]
            ELSE @status
        END),
projectTypeCode =
    (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@projectTypeCode,'')='' THEN projectTypeCode
            ELSE @projectTypeCode
        END),
projectManager =
    (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(@projectManager,'')='' THEN projectManager
            ELSE @projectManager
        END)
WHERE @projectID=projectID
```

Comment: You do not have to pass all of the parameters, however if you elect to do so, using parameter defaults or value checking as described above would be prudent.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: How would write the update statement if all of the parameters aren't passed?

Comment: Unsure the question april, but an update statement does not require every column in the table to be set  [Try It Yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp) and if you need it to be dynamic which columns it updates, you would write 'red' code or dynmaic sql to build the update statement and call the string with an execute statement. see the dynamic sql in a procedure section [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-1)